# Question about using sum of quadratic residue to count points on elliptic curve in Schoof's paper

Tags: elliptic-curves, quadratic-residues

Sorry, I have a very basic question about Schoof's paper, when he is talking about taking the sum of quadratic residues to count points.

"This implies that evaluating the sum $$\sum_{x \in F_p} \left(\frac{x^3 + Ax + B}{p} \right)$$ is the same problem as computing $\#E(F_p)$".

He then says: 
"In practice it is convenient to make first a table of squares modulo $p$" and then count how often $x^3 + Ax + B$ is a square for $x = 0, 1, ..., p-1$."

I've stared at it for a long time but I don't really understand this process.  Sorry if this is really basic but I would really appreciate if someone can explain. 
So for example if we have $p = 3$ and elliptic curve $C: y^2 = x^3 +1$, then how does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the curve you offered is not elliptic, since when $p=3$, we have $x^3+1=(x+1)^3$. Let’s perform the task for $y^2=x^3-x$ in case $p=3$ and in case $p=5$.

When you evaluate $x^3-x$ for $x=0,1,2\in\Bbb F_3$, you get zero every time, and there is only one $y$ with $y^2=0$, so that there are three points in the “finite” plane, giving a total of four when you count the point $\Bbb O$ at infinity.

More interestingly, when you work in $\Bbb F_5$ and evaluate $x^3-x$ at $0,1,2,3,4$, you can check that the values are $0,0,1,4,0$. The zero values contribute one each to the total count, and since both $1$ and $4$ are squares in $\Bbb F_5$, you get two points on the curve when $x$ is each of $2$ and $3$. Including $\Bbb O$ again, you get a total count of eight points on the curve.

You’ll find that when you do the same computation for $y^2=x^3-x$ at $p=7$, some evaluations of $x^3-x$ give a nonsquare like $6$ or $3$, and then there is *no* contribution to the totality of points on the curve.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer, it helped me get some more intuition with some clear examples and that is really valuable. I still have confusion about one thing. Like in your example for $\mathbb{F}_5$, in the example you gave we are evaluating the function for all points in the field and then modding out by $p$. I understand that we can count squares in p as 2 points and 0 as one point. But then in the way he mentions, we first "construct a table mod p" and then "count the number of times $x^3 - x$ is a square. By "is a square" does he mean *with* the mod? And if not, how does this help?

Comment: I guess I actually mean: in the case that he means count the number of times $x^3 - x$ is a square *with* the mod, then how is this different from the sum itself, where we are just modding the function evaluated at all x in the field by $p$ and seeing if it is congruent to a square? Otherwise, if it's the case that he means *without* the mod, then like in your example, where $p= 5$, none of the values for $x^3 - x$ are perfect squares... so how does this help us?

Comment: Yes, as you say, “with the mod”. It’s all happening with computations in the field $\Bbb F_p$ of integers modulo $p$. I hope you did the computation in $\Bbb F_7$, where the squares are $0,1,2,4$. So, even though $2$ is not a square integer, we do have $2=3^2=4^2$ in $\Bbb F_7$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand now that everything takes place in the field